# customized .4ht files keep in a particular path

Tags: tex4ht

How to configure a customized .4ht and .cfg file which kept in a particular folder when doing HTML conversion?

Regards,
MadYuv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was working when we give the folder path in conversion tag, i.e., `htlatex filename "d:\test\custom,xhtml" " -cunihft" "-cvalidate -p"`, then the conversion tool fetch the custom.cfg and .4ht file from the specified path, thanks to all